# Inertia tensor as two times contravariant pseudotensor

Tags: rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

I need to prove that the inertia tensor is a (2,0) pseudotensors, how can i do it? I keep getting that is a two times contravariant tensor, and that is what every source i checked says.

Comment: what definitions are you working from?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that you are considering the angular-velocity as a pseudovector

so that the moment-of-inertia must be a pseudotensor 
that maps two pseudovectors to an ordinary scalar
$$T=\frac{1}{2} \omega^a I_{ab} \omega^b.$$

You might find this  passage from Synge and Schild's Tensor Calculus (1949, 1969, Dover:1978, ISBN 9780486636122  ) interesting. Do a "Google book search" in it for   *"moment of inertia"* and get to page 161 to read about the **fourth-order moment of inertia tensor in N-dimensions**.

I'll transcribe some portions here..

> To compute the angular momentum, we use 5.310, where
> $\omega_{rm}$ is the angular velocity tensor of the body.
> Then
> $$
> \begin{align}
> h_{np} 
> &= \sum m\left(\omega_{nq}z_qz_p— \omega_{pq}z_q z_n \right) \quad (5.329)\\
> &= J_{nprq}\omega_{rq}
> \end{align}
> $$
> where
> $$
> \begin{align}
> J_{nprq}&= \sum m\left(\delta_{nr}z_pz_q— \delta_{pr}z_n z_q \right) \quad (5.330)
> \end{align}
> $$
> This may be called the *fourth-order moment of inertia tensor.*
> The equations of motion 5.328 now may be written
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \frac{d}{dt}(J_{nprq} \omega_{rq})&= M_{np}\quad (5.331)
> \end{align}
> $$

[ $M_{np}$ was defined above as the tensor moment of forces ]

> Let us see what becomes of this formula when N = 3.
>
> ...
> $$I_{st}=\frac{1}{2} J_{nprq} \epsilon_{rqt} \epsilon_{snp} \quad (5.333)$$
> ...
> $$I_{st}=\sum m \epsilon_{ptq} \epsilon_{psn} z_q z_n  \quad (5.334)$$
> ...
> $$I_{st}=\delta_{st}\sum m  z_q z_q - \sum mz_s z_t  \quad (5.335)$$
> ...
>
> which will be recognized as the usual moments and products of inertia, the latter with signs reversed. The symmetric tensor
> $I_{st}$ is commonly called the *moment of inertia tensor*.
> It is interesting to see how the three-dimensionality of space effects the
> reduction from the fourth-order tensor $J_{nprq}$ to the
> second-order tensor $I_{st}$.

Comment: That book's expression for $J$ isn't wrong per se, but it doesn't antisymmetrize over the first or the last pair of indices, so it includes spurious degrees of freedom. It's maybe okay not to antisymmetrize over the input pair, since it gets contracted with an antisymmetric two-form, but they really should antisymmetrize over the output pair so that the output is antisymmetric. I prefer the expression in https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560, which explicitly antisymmetrizes and makes the index symmetries more explicit.