# What's the physical intepretation of the Weyl tensor term in the tensor of inertia?

Tags: general-relativity, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, curvature, moment-of-inertia

According to https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560, for rigid-body motion in arbitrary dimensions, the relationship between the angular momentum two-form $L$ and angular velocity two-form $\omega$ is given by
$$L_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} I_{ijkl} \omega_{kl},$$
where $I$ is the rank-four tensor of inertia defined by
$$I_{ijkl} := 4 \int dm \left( x_{[j} \delta_{i][k} x_{l]} \right).$$

Interestingly, the tensor of inertia is an [algebraic curvature tensor](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212278), meaning that it has the same index symmetries (and therefore the same algebraic degrees of freedom) as the Riemann curvature tensor. [This paper](https://physics.byu.edu/docs/publication/485) (PDF) tries to explain the reason behind this surprising parallel, but it uses some obscure math involving the geometric algebra, and I personally don't find it very illuminating.

On any algebraic curvature tensor, we can perform the [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition), which decomposes the tensor as a sum of three terms, which contain the same information as (a) the doubly-contracted scalar invariant $I_{ijij}$, (b) the traceless part of the singly-contracted rank-two tensor $I_{kikj}$, and (c) everything else not contained within that rank-two tensor, respectively. The last term, the Weyl tensor, turns out to be conformally invariant, but can only be nonzero in $d>3$ dimensions.

The Weyl tensor summand in the Ricci decomposition of the inertia tensor should reflect the existence of some qualitatively new physical phenomena about rigid-body rotation that only appears in $d>3$, just as the Weyl tensor in general relativity reflects the existence of gravitational waves, black holes with extended influence, etc. in general relativity with $D>3$.  What's the physical interpretation of this piece of the tensor of inertia in $d>3$ dimensions?

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question. I've also wondered about rigid-body mechanics in n-dimensions via this fourth-order tensor.

However, I don't have an answer to your specific question.
But I can offer a reference which may be of use. (Interestingly, none of the two papers (Jensen https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560 and Berrondo https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4734014 ) you link to mention this reference.)

From my answer to
[Inertia tensor as two times contravariant pseudotensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692403/inertia-tensor-as-two-times-contravariant-pseudotensor/692418#692418)

> Synge and Schild's Tensor Calculus (1949, 1969, Dover:1978, ISBN 9780486636122 ). Do a "Google book search" in it for "moment of inertia" and get to page 161 to read about the **fourth-order moment of inertia tensor in N-dimensions**.

These may also be helpful

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulkarni%E2%80%93Nomizu_product